# Invalid transactionID

Tags: api, paypal

Problem : Transaction Id is not Valid in DoVoid Method [API call] in Paypal Payment Pro[Direct payment]. Using NVP(Name Value Pair).

I have made a test application to use Paypal Payment Pro [Direct payment].
I have successfully made the API cal for Payment `[Method Name="DoDirectPayment"]` and `[Refund Method Name="RefundTransaction "]`.

please Refer `"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/"` for Do Direct Payment Method

Now i want to make a payment Cancel. I am now using [DoVoid Method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoVoid_API_Operation_NVP/) .

I am Passing The Transaction Id in AUTHORIZATIONID, But in response i am Getting Failure and `ErrorMsg="Transaction Id is Invalid"`

**Response** :`"TIMESTAMP=2014-03-20T11:17:47Z&CORRELATIONID=806e38eec5474&ACK=Failure&VERSION=98.0&BUILD=10030158&L_ERRORCODE0=10609&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid transactionID.&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Transaction id is invalid.&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error"`

In DoVoid method there is a parameter called AUTHORIZATIONID where it is asking for Authorization ID or The **Order ID** .

From where to get the Order Id in the Response of DoDirectPayment Method so I can use that in DoVoid Method For Voiding the Transaction.

Please get me the Answer for this as soon as possible. If any query, please revert me on spathai04@gmail.com

Thanks & Regards
Sunny
spathai04@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order ID's would only be associated with Express Checkout orders.  When working with DoDirectPayment you won't have that.

In your case, it sounds like your original DDP request was sent as a Sale transaction.  These cannot be voided.

Instead, run the DDP as an Authorization.  This will create the authorization transaction which can then be captured with DoCapture or voided with DoVoid.  When necessary, you could use DoReauthorization to extend the auth period as well.

Comment: are you sure i cannot use DoVoid Method in Direct payment. And if yes the any other Alternative for Cancelling the Order.

Comment: As long as the DoDirectPayment was called with Authorization instead of Sale, then yes it can be voided via DoVoid.  If you just "do nothing" to an authorization it'll expire after about 29 days or so depending on the bank.  If the original transaction was a sale, though, or if the Authorization has already been captured, all you can do is refund it.

Comment: I am https://github.com/MultiSafepay/laravel-api for payment. On Github document I have fire direct
Route::get('test', function () {
        return $transaction = multisafepayTransactionManager('apikey', 'test')->get('1');
    }); but I have see error MultiSafepay\Exception\ApiException
Invalid transaction ID . why? I dont understand how data I will provide for order,price and customer in this laravel 8 package.